# Byte v/s character oriented stream - Java

Tags: java, file, inputstream

I have read about both the these. I want to know:

1) When to choose one over the other while reading or writing files?

2) Any pros and cons over one another?

Please advice.

Comment: Well, that depends. What kind of files are you trying to read or write? Binary or text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use character streams to read text files. Do not forget to specify encodings in you use them. Otherwise, use byte streams.